# How to round a number using mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I need to fetch the data from mongo db collection, perform arithmatic operation and then round the result, and update the result as a new field in the same collection. How to achieve this in mongodb?

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc){
    percentage = 100- ((doc.offer_price/doc.mrp)*100);
        db.collection.aggregate([{$project:{ 
                  npercentage:{$divide:[
                      {$subtract:[
                            {$add:[499.99,percentage]},
                            {$mod:[
                               {$add:[499.99,percentage]},
                               1000
                            ]}
                      ]},
                      1000
                ]}} } ] );
        db.collection.update(
        { "_id": doc._id, "category_name":"main"},
        { "$set": { "percentage_saved": npercentage  } }
    )
});
```

The above query doesn't work but need to achieve something similar.Please Help!

Comment: What is `.aggregate()` doing in there? You are not using the result so it appears to have no purpose. What in fact is your question? How to get a rounded amount in a query? Or how to update with a rounded amount? What is it you actually expect?

Comment: Ahh!!  .aggregate doesnt go right there. I was just trying to get the round amount there that i have to update in collection. Basically I have to calculate the amount and then update the round amount in my collection.

Comment: "The above query corrupts my mongodb". No. As long as your data is readable, it isn't "corrupted". It "is brought to an unusual/undesired state by the user" would be more fitting.

Comment: Do you think you might correct this to make it clear what you are actually trying to do. I kind of get that you seem to be wanting to update something with either a "reduced price" or something like that. But cleaning up the statement would go a long way to making a clear statement about what you are actually trying to achieve here.

Comment: I would be really thankful if anyone can help me out with the solution.